# Arrays.AsList and addAll

Tags: java

does someone could explain to me what is a diffrence?

```
private List<Coin> mycCoins = new ArrayList<>();

public Purse(Coin...coins) {
    myCoins = Arrays.asList(coins);
    myCoins.addAll(Arrays.asList(coins));
}
```

between these myCoins?

and why i cannot do so

```
mycCoins.addAll(coins);
```

and actually it would be interesting to know if i wrote this way

```
for (Coin coin : coins) {
        mycCoins.add(coin);
```

how this way differs from those that i mentioned above

Please help me, and explain it to me

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.asList(coins)` gives you a brand new list, but its not the usual type of `ArrayList`.  It's a special type of list with a fixed size array underneath, which means you can't add or remove elements in it.  It's stuck at the original size of `coins` although you can modify the values in it.

`addAll(something)` adds the coins to a list you've already got, which can be any kind of `List`.  You can call it on an `ArrayList` that you've already created, and the number of elements will actually increase.

The thing you pass to `addAll` can't be an array though, it has to be some kind of `Collection`, because that's the way `addAll` is defined.  In most cases, the simplest thing to do is to pass it one of the unresizeable lists that you get from `Array.asList`, so something like

```
myList.addAll(Arrays.asList(coins));
```

Answer (score 0):

because `addAll` is defined as:

```
addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

it can only take a collection as an argument. `coins` is not a collection.

when you do:

```
for(Coin coin : coins)
   myCoins.add(coin)
```

This is fine because you're adding a `Coin` reference to a `List<Coin>`.

Comment: You should also mention that it will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` since OP used `Arrays#asList` and is trying to add to it.

Comment: @JacobG. I guess you could use `arrayList.addAll(new ArrayList(asList(...)))` no?

Comment: @JacobG. out of context for this question, but I have a feeling that it's a typo, instead of `myCoins.addAll(Arrays.asList(coins));` I think the OP meant to do `mycCoins.addAll(myCoins);` and assuming that _is_ indeed what the OP meant, the said exception should not occur.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that actually.  I don't know why OP named both `List`s so similarly lol.

Comment: @YassinHajaj it's redundant to do `arrayList.addAll(new ArrayList(asList(...)))`, instead `arrayList.addAll(asList(...))` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

> myCoins = Arrays.asList(coins); // OK
>
> > Arrays.asList(E) returns List and you are assigning this to ArryaList
>
> myCoins.addAll(Arrays.asList(coins)); // OK
>
> > Collection method addAll takes Collection as first parameter. Arrays.asList returns a collection 
> >     From javadocs on Collection -> addAll(Collection c)
>
> myCoins.addAll(coins); // NOT OK
>
> > coins is a vararg in your code.  Compiler treats varargs as an array. "addAll" does not take [] as param
>
> for (Coin coin : coins) { myCoins.add(coin); // OK
>
> > As you are traversing the coins array and adding each object.